# different result for css style in chrome and IE

Tags: cross-browser

so here I tried to do some styling, mainly for positioning, here's my code:

```
<td>
   <img src="images/master/login_box.png" style="width: 351px; height: 280px; position: relative;
                margin-top: 35px; left: 14px" />

   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LOGIN" Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="13"
                ForeColor="White" Style="position: absolute; margin-top: -235px; margin-left: 35px"></asp:Label>

   <img src="images/master/Lock.png" style="width: 12px; height: 16px; position: absolute;
                margin-top: -235px; margin-left: 97px" />

   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="REGISTER" Font-Names="Century Gothic"
                Font-Size="13" ForeColor="White" Style="position: absolute; margin-top: -235px;
                margin-left: 260px"></asp:Label>

   <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="User" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11"
                ForeColor="White" Style="position: absolute; top: 142px; margin-left: 35px"></asp:Label>

   <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="225px" Height="30px" Style="position: absolute;
                top: 133px; margin-left: 110px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;"></asp:TextBox>

   <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Password" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="11"
                ForeColor="White" Style="position: absolute; top: 190px; margin-left: 35px"></asp:Label>

   <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassw" runat="server" Width="225px" Height="30px" Style="position: absolute;
                top: 180px; margin-left: 110px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;"></asp:TextBox>

   <ul id="submit" style="position: absolute; top: 230px; margin-left: 110px">
                <li id="submit-1"><a href="#" title="Submit"><span>Submit</span></a></li>
            </ul>

    <img src="images/master/info.png" style="width: 10px; height: 11px; position: absolute;
                top: 277px; right: 160px" />

    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Forgot Password |" Font-Names="Century Gothic"
                Font-Size="7" ForeColor="White" Font-Italic="true" Style="position: absolute;
                top: 273px; right: 70px"></asp:Label>

    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Reactivate" Font-Names="Century Gothic"
                Font-Size="7" ForeColor="White" Font-Italic="true" Style="position: absolute;
                top: 273px; right: 15px"></asp:Label>

</td>
```

the issue is, the positioning in chrome is great, it stays where it should be (label, textbox, etc), but when I tried in IE, the positioning is not right, especially for the (LOGIN, lock.png, REGISTER, User and Password Label and textbox) they go to the corner of the screen. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong? some friendly suggestion would be nice, thanks.

Comment: Which IE version are you using ?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that you suppose that all the browsers render same code in same way.  A friendly suggestion: find out which CSS property is not rendered as you expect it, then try to find a solution to a particular problem. A friendly suggestion (not related with the question): separate the page structure from the page styling.

Comment: @Amine i'm using IE 9

Comment: Does it look the same on Firefox, Safari... as on Chrome ?

Comment: @Kolyunya what do you mean separate the page structure from the page styling? :)

Comment: @AbieGiordano I mean that it's not always a good practice to have CSS inside of HTML elements. It's a common advise to move CSS to external files of to header and apply only CSS classes and ids to HTML elements.

Comment: @Amine i've tried it on firefox and it renders it well, on safari, well, haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @Kolyunya oh, i understand now, so i just create a .css file and link it to my page right? i've done that a few hours ago, but still the same issue. any advice?

Comment: @AbieGiordano find out which particular CSS option is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Changing the login_box.png position to absolute instead of relative fixed the issue :D